# Gedit Code Tree (Code Structure)

Tags: plugins, code, gedit

I'm currently using `Gedit` for writing some code. Is it possible to show a code tree/structure in `Gedit` (like on the picture below)? The example on the picture is from `CudaText` editor.

[image: Code Tree]

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for something more akin to an IDE than a text editor like Gedit. Try VS Code/VS Codium.

Comment: @gronostaj, I used some IDEs some time ago, but now I find `Gedit` more convenient for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it possible to show a code tree/structure in Gedit

Yes. You need to enable plug-ins and install gedit-classbrowser3g:

> Class Browser for gedit
>
> **The class browser is located in the side pane and lists functions,
> classes, etc. in a tree view.** The default parser uses exuberant ctags
> (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to support a wide range of languages
> (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html). Special parsers are
> used for Python, HTML, XML/Mallard/DocBook, Diff, Ruby, Markdown and
> Changelogs.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [gedit-classbrowser3g in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/gedit-classbrowser3g)

See Also:

- [Useful Gedit plugins for programmers](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/three-useful-gedit-plugins-for-programmers/)
- [Apps/Gedit/Attic/ThirdPartyPlugins/v3.8 - GNOME Wiki!](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Attic/ThirdPartyPlugins/v3.8)

Comment: David, thank you for your answer! I installed the plugin and activated in `Preferences` but cannot figure out how to make it appear in the side panel. [Here is what I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoCFc.png)

Comment: Sorry, don't use GEdit myself so I've no idea why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I've edited the plugin's code and somehow managed to make it show in the side panel. But it doesn't update when a code gets changed. Continue working on it…

Comment: I didn't manage to make it update the tree on typing, but the tree updates on saving and I managed to get rid of errors.